# In DataPrep, How to create connection with instance of sql without public ip on google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, vpc-peering, google-cloud-vpn

In Dataprep, when creating the connection there is the 'Test Connection' button, after filling in all the connection data, with the private ip, port, username and password, I click on the test button and I get the error [Unable to connect to host] SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out.

I correctly configured the subnetwork settings in the 'execution settings' preferences, as indicated in this link https://community.trifacta.com/s/article/Configure-Dataprep-to-run-Dataflow-jobs-in-a-custom-VPC

My SQL instance on google cloud platform has no public ip, only private ip, I'm not getting dataprep to connect to the database, how should I proceed, is there any additional configuration for it to work?

I'm also not able to find material and documentation about this, if you can help me, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the dataprep quickstart guide from Trifacta? It seems to me you're missing something from the network layer. I'm not an expert on Dataprep since it's a third party partnership, but the quickstart guide below has very simple steps to follow for connecting your database and specifically mentions cloud SQL. You may have to create an INGRESS ALLOW firewall rule to a allow their IP range to access that database instance based on the line below.

"NOTE: The database to which you are connecting must be available from the Trifacta service over the public Internet."

https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/Getting+Started+with+Dataprep+by+Trifacta
https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/Connection+Types#ConnectionTypes-DefaultConnections